# What does heuristic h: {1, ... , N} --> R mean?

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence, heuristics

I want to know what does a heuristic `h: {1, ... , N} --> R` with the goal state always being 1 mean?

The state are represented as points in a 2D Cartesian system, with coordinates (x,y).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Notation) describes this notation of a function. In your specific case:

`h: {1, ..., N] --> R`

we have:

- `h`: The function's symbol (h for heuristic)
- `{1, ..., N}`: the domain of your function, in this case the set of all integers from 1 up to and including N. This is the ''input'' that your function can take. Note that this means that your function `h(x)` is not, for example, defined for `x = 1.5`. It can only take integers between 1 and N (both inclusive) as input.
- `R`: The codomain of your functions, in this case the set `R` which is probably supposed to denote the set of all [real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number). Your function can produce any real number as output.